# Does Flame Blade count as a weapon for Green-Flame Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, attack

The description for the [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) spell (SCAG, p. 143) says:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range.

It doesn't specify that the "attack with a weapon" can't be a "spell attack with a weapon".

**Does the effect conjured by [*flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-blade) count as a weapon or not and therefore be used in conjunction with *green-flame blade*?**

It doesn't say in the spell description of *flame blade*. It only states it is similar in size and shape to a scimitar which sounds strikingly like a weapon to me.

Answer (score 43):

### No, it doesn't.

In fact, you can't even use a [*Flame Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-blade) spell as part of an Attack (action).

The spell states:

> You evoke a fiery blade in your free hand. The blade is similar in size and shape to a scimitar, and it lasts for the duration. If you let go of the blade, it disappears, but you can evoke the blade again as a bonus action.
>
> You can **use your action** to make a **melee spell attack** with the fiery blade. On a hit, the target takes 3d6 fire damage.

The only mechanical uses of the the fiery blade are its unique action (make a melee spell attack, deal 3d6 fire damage on hit), and its ability to shed light.

Since you can't make a **melee weapon attack** with it, it isn't a weapon, and thus can't be used in conjunction with [*Green-Flame Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade).

Compare this to the spell [*Shadow Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shadow-blade) (from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 164) which says:

> You weave together threads of shadow to create a sword of solidified gloom in your hand. This magic sword lasts until the spell ends. It **counts as a simple melee weapon** with which you are proficient. It deals 2d8 psychic damage on a hit and has the finesse, light, and thrown properties (range 20/60). [...]

The spell description specifically states that the effect counts as a weapon, and it defines the weapon's properties.

Answer (score 3):

### You can't combine the spells because you only have one action on your turn.

Although [GreySage's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129843/32426) excellently explains why the fiery blade produced by *flame blade* does not count as a weapon usable as part of casting *green-flame blade*, there is an additional and substantial reason you cannot combine these two spells: the action economy.

The text for [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) explains that you must make an attack as part of the action used to cast it (the Cast a Spell action).

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon...

The text for [*flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-blade) explains that using the fiery blade it creates requires you to use an action to make the attack (this special action doesn't have a name—it is granted by the spell effect).

> You can use your action to make a melee spell attack with the fiery blade.

If you've already used your action on your turn to use the Cast a Spell action, you can't also use the special action granted by *flame blade*, since you only have one action on your turn. (Even if you're a Fighter using Action Surge, the actions are resolved separately, so an attack made as part of Cast a Spell can't also somehow be the same attack made as part of the special action of *flame blade*.)

Answer (score 3):

#### The text of Green Flame Blade was errata-ed.

The text of [*Green Flame Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) spell [has been modified since 2021](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf)<sup>1</sup> , and now it states:

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell’s casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you.

and the required material component is a melee weapon worth at least 1 sp.

The caster then needs an actual weapon for casting *Green Flame Blade*, but [*Flame Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-blade) does not create any weapon, just a magical effect that

> is similar in size and shape to a scimitar.

---

<sup>1</sup> [*Booming Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) has been modified in a similar way.